# encode each string element in list of strings to list of numbers within R dataframe columns

Tags: r, encoding, dummy-variable

I'm new to R, looking to implement what's seen in this post: [Create dummy variables from string with multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52527897/create-dummy-variables-from-string-with-multiple-values) for every column in my df.That is, I would like to encode each string element to a dummy variable and then store each back to a list as it's encoded value.  I've done this in Python but am not sure of the best way to go about this in R. Please find Expected Output Below.
CURRENTLY

```
|          Databases                               |            Cryptocurrency                              |          Visual

|:------------------------------------------------:|:------------------------------------------------------:|:----------------------------------------------------------:|

|c("PostgreSQL","MySQL","SQL")                     |c("Ethereum","Cryptocurrency","Bitcoin","Blockchain")   |c("BrandDesign","GraphicDesign","LogoDesign","PackageDesign")
| MSSQLManagement                                  |character(0)                                            |c("BrandDesign", "GraphicDesign", "LogoDesign")
|c("MongoDB","Redis","MySQL")                      |c("Bitcoin", "Blockchain")                              |character(0)
|c("RedisManagement")                              | Cryptocurrency                                         |c("BrandDesign", "GraphicDesign")
|c("MySQL","MemcachedManagement","MongoDB","Redis")|c("Cryptocurrency", "Ethereum", "Blockchain")           | GraphicDesign
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
| Databases |  Cryptocurrency  |   Visual     |

|:---------:|:----------------:|:------------:|

|c(1,2,3)   |c(1,2,3,4)        |c(1,2,3,4)    |
| 4         | 0                |c(1, 2, 3)    |
|c(5,6,2)   |c(3, 4)           | 0            |
|c(6)       | 2                |c(1, 2)       |
|c(2,7,5,6) |c(2, 1, 4)        | 2            |
```

The end goal is to train the data on a KNN Model.

EDIT:
The following output is output of **dput(df[1:25, c(11, 17)])**:

```
structure(list(Technical = list(c("Architecture", "TechnicalDesign", 
"Documentation", "RequirementsGathering"), character(0), character(0), 
    c("Documentation", "TechnicalDesign", "RequirementsGathering"
    ), c("Architecture", "TechnicalDesign", "Documentation", 
    "RequirementsGathering"), c("Architecture", "TechnicalDesign", 
    "Documentation", "RequirementsGathering"), c("Architecture", 
    "TechnicalDesign", "Documentation", "RequirementsGathering"
    ), character(0), c("Architecture", "Documentation", "RequirementsGathering"
    ), c("Architecture", "TechnicalDesign", "Documentation", 
    "RequirementsGathering"), c("Architecture", "TechnicalDesign", 
    "Documentation", "RequirementsGathering"), c("Architecture", 
    "TechnicalDesign", "Documentation", "RequirementsGathering"
    ), c("Architecture", "TechnicalDesign", "Documentation", 
    "RequirementsGathering"), c("Architecture", "TechnicalDesign", 
    "Documentation", "RequirementsGathering"), c("Architecture", 
    "TechnicalDesign", "Documentation", "RequirementsGathering"
    ), c("Documentation", "TechnicalDesign", "RequirementsGathering"
    ), character(0), character(0), c("Architecture", "TechnicalDesign", 
    "Documentation", "RequirementsGathering"), c("Architecture", 
    "TechnicalDesign", "Documentation", "RequirementsGathering"
    )), Tools = list(c("Photoshop", "Sketch", "InVision", "Illustrator", 
"Zeplin"), c("GoogleAnalytics", "GoogleAdsense", "MailChimp", 
"GoogleAdwords"), character(0), c("FacebookAds", "GoogleAnalytics", 
"MailChimp"), c("FacebookAds", "GoogleAnalytics", "MailChimp"
), c("Kubernetes", "Vagrant"), c("Gulp", "Vagrant"), character(0), 
    c("GoogleAnalytics", "GoogleAdwords"), c("Hubspot", "Kissmetrics", 
    "InstagramAds", "FacebookAds", "LinkedInAds", "Optimizely", 
    "GoogleAnalytics"), "GoogleAnalytics", c("FacebookAds", "GoogleAnalytics", 
    "GoogleAdsense", "InstagramAds", "GoogleAdwords"), c("GoogleAnalytics", 
    "TwitterAds", "MailChimp"), c("GoogleAnalytics", "MailChimp", 
    "Mixpanel"), c("GoogleAnalytics", "MailChimp", "GoogleAdwords"
    ), c("Photoshop", "Sketch", "InVision", "Illustrator"), character(0), 
    character(0), character(0), c("FacebookAds", "GoogleAnalytics", 
    "Optimizely", "GoogleAdwords", "Mixpanel")), ProjectManagement = list(
    c("AgileMethodology", "ClientManagement", "Scrum"), c("AgileMethodology", 
    "ClientManagement", "Scrum"), "ClientManagement", c("AgileMethodology", 
    "ClientManagement", "Scrum"), c("AgileMethodology", "ClientManagement", 
    "Scrum"), c("AgileMethodology", "Scrum"), c("AgileMethodology", 
    "ClientManagement"), character(0), c("AgileMethodology", 
    "ClientManagement", "Scrum"), c("AgileMethodology", "ClientManagement", 
    "Scrum"), c("AgileMethodology", "Scrum"), c("AgileMethodology", 
    "ClientManagement", "Scrum"), character(0), c("ClientManagement", 
    "Scrum"), c("AgileMethodology", "Scrum"), c("AgileMethodology", 
    "ClientManagement", "Scrum"), c("AgileMethodology", "Scrum"
    ), "AgileMethodology", c("AgileMethodology", "Scrum"), c("AgileMethodology", 
    "Scrum")), Visual = list(c("BrandDesign", "GraphicDesign", 
"LogoDesign", "PackageDesign"), c("BrandDesign", "GraphicDesign", 
"LogoDesign"), character(0), character(0), c("BrandDesign", "GraphicDesign", 
"LogoDesign", "PackageDesign"), character(0), character(0), character(0), 
    character(0), c("BrandDesign", "GraphicDesign", "LogoDesign"
    ), character(0), character(0), c("BrandDesign", "GraphicDesign", 
    "LogoDesign", "PackageDesign"), c("BrandDesign", "GraphicDesign", 
    "LogoDesign", "PackageDesign"), character(0), character(0), 
    character(0), character(0), character(0), c("BrandDesign", 
    "GraphicDesign", "LogoDesign")), ConfigurationManagement = list(
    character(0), "Chef", character(0), character(0), character(0), 
    c("Ansible", "Terraform", "Puppet"), character(0), character(0), 
    character(0), c("Puppet", "Chef"), c("Terraform", "Chef"), 
    character(0), character(0), character(0), character(0), character(0), 
    character(0), character(0), "Chef", character(0)), Containers = list(
    character(0), "Docker", character(0), character(0), character(0), 
    "Docker", "Docker", "Docker", "Docker", "Docker", "Docker", 
    "Docker", character(0), character(0), "Docker", "Docker", 
    character(0), character(0), "Docker", "Docker"), Cryptocurrency = list(
    character(0), character(0), character(0), character(0), character(0), 
    c("Ethereum", "Cryptocurrency", "Bitcoin", "Blockchain"), 
    character(0), character(0), character(0), c("Ethereum", "Cryptocurrency", 
    "Bitcoin", "Blockchain"), c("Solidity", "Ethereum", "Cryptocurrency", 
    "Bitcoin", "Blockchain"), c("Solidity", "Ethereum", "Cryptocurrency", 
    "Bitcoin", "Blockchain"), character(0), character(0), character(0), 
    character(0), character(0), character(0), character(0), character(0))), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a function that recodes the values.

```
recode_values <- function(x) {
  x1 <- strsplit(x, ',\\s*')
  relist(match(unlist(x1), unique(unlist(x1))), x1)
}
```

Clean the string and apply it to multiple columns.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(across(c(AutomatedTesting, Cryptocurrency), 
             ~recode_values(gsub("\\[|\\]|'", "", .))))

#   AutomatedTesting Cryptocurrency
#1                                 
#2        1, 2, 3, 4               
#3                 1               
#4                 2               
#5                                 
#6              2, 1     1, 2, 3, 4
#7           1, 2, 5               
#8              2, 1               
#9           2, 3, 1               
#10    1, 2, 6, 3, 5     1, 2, 3, 4
#11          2, 6, 1  5, 1, 2, 3, 4
#12             2, 1  5, 1, 2, 3, 4
#13                                
#14                                
#15    1, 2, 6, 3, 4               
#16       1, 2, 6, 5               
#17          2, 3, 1               
#18                                
#19                2               
#20 4, 5, 6, 3, 1, 2               
#21             2, 4               
#22 4, 5, 6, 3, 1, 2               
#23             2, 1               
#24          2, 6, 1               
#25       2, 6, 3, 1
```

Comment: This is amazing! I'm not able to run using the across function? Getting "Error in across(c(AutomatedTesting, Experience, Technical, Tools, ProjectManagement,  : 
  could not find function "across". I read that across should work with devtools? And I installed using the following code: 
install.packages("devtools"); devtools::install_github("tidyverse/dplyr"). But across is still not working for me. What packages do you have installed that allow you to run your code?

Comment: `across` is available in `dplyr` 1.0.0 or above. `install.packages('dplyr')` should give you that. If you are not able to use `across` you can use `mutate_at` instead. `df %>% mutate_at(vars(AutomatedTesting, Cryptocurrency), ~recode_values(gsub("\\[|\\]|'", "", .)))`